# Ionic 2 Offline

Tags: ionic, sqlite

Boa Noite!
Eu estou com um app criado no Ionic e todas as informações atualmente estão online em um servidor e o app faz a requisição, o servidor retorna os dados, monta a página e Ok. Mas irá chegar em um ponto que algumas dessas informações deverá ser mostradas offline. É possível/viável por conta das limitações de internet gravar parte desses dados online no storage offline ou em um SqLite para que possam ter acesso a algumas informações?
Ou tem formas de alimentar esse storage ou Sqlite de forma automática a partir desse mysql online?
Obrigado

Comment: Sim é possível. Dai o resto ira depender da quantidade de informação que será gravada. Se for pouca o Storage resolve, se muita, o SqlLite será a melhor opção.

Comment: Opa, legal saber Cassio. Você recomenda ou tem algum exemplo/tutorial para se basear para implementar isso?

Comment: Que tipos de dados você quer gravar?

Comment: eu desejo gravar numeros e texto(varchar 50 max)...esses números seriam como se fosse cupons para as pessoas

Comment: então este link ira te ajudar: https://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/

Comment: Cassio agradeço sua atenção cara! Obrigado

Comment: Tomara que dê certo.